# How to make vscode refer to a .py file when I click on a python method?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

When I press ctrl+click on a built-in or library function method, it redirects me not to the source file of that method, but to a stub .pyi file, which is wildly annoying. For example, if I go to print() function, the IDE will open builtins.pyi file instead of builtins.py. I know this problem doesn't exist in PyCharm, but I want to work in vscode.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @S.B Unfortunately, no(

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `.env` file in root of your project and put path to `python` there, like that:

`PYTHONPATH=~/.venv/bin/python3`

If needed, use `:` as a separator in case of multiple paths.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help me. I use pipenv and folder `.venv` is inside my project. In the file `.env` I specified `PYTHONPATH=~/.venv/bin/python3` and rebooted VSCode. But when I press ⌘ + LBM, I still end up in stub files (.pyi ). What am I doing wrong?